# Access sfConfig class in apps/appname/lib

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a symfony 1.4 application with some classes for connecting to a SOAP web service stored in apps/appname/lib.  When I try to access the `sfConfig` class to get some variables I have set in `app.yml`, an error is thrown since the application doesn't recognize `sfConfig::get('app_myvar')` as a method being called on a class.

How do I make the `sfConfig` class available to the classes in my apps/appname/lib directory?

This is the error I'm getting

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /Users/my/Sites/mySite/apps/frontend/lib/mySOAP.class.php on line 9
```

And here is the top of my class:

```
class mySOAP extends SoapClient  {
  protected $client = null;
  protected $soapUrl = sfConfig::get('app_my_url');
  protected $options = array(
    'trace'             => 1,
    'exceptions'        => 1,
    'soap_version'      => SOAP_1_2,
    //'encoding'            => 'ISO-8859-1',
    'features'          => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
```

Line 9 is

```
protected $soapUrl = sfConfig::get('app_my_url');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sfConfig` class is loaded automatically when the Symfony stack is 'booted'. So either your running through the `index.php` (or any other frontend controller) or the CLI, you should have access to the `sfConfig`.

So my best guess is that you either haven't successfully set up the Symfony stack (though this should throw other errors in an earlier stage), or your trying to access the `app.yml` from a script outside `Symfony`? In the latter case, you could either boot up Symfony or include the `sfYaml` parser and parse the `app.yml` yourself.

Comment: The stack trace on my app show that I'm loading the Symfony stack.  I think I need to find a way to add an interface in my class declaration so it has access to the sfConfig class.  Right now, my custom class just extends the stock php SoapClient class

Comment: sfConfig is (one of the few) global classes in Symfony. Once booted, you should be able to access it. Could you please expand your question with some code samples (the function where your calling it), and a precise error message?

Comment: I've just posted my error message, back working on this project after a month.  Anyway, judging from the error, I hope it's something dumb I'm doing :)

Comment: First off: you shouldn't (can't) assign the value for `$soapUrl` directly after it's declaration. You should assign it in the constructor.
Second: can you indicate which line is line 9? The error you're getting is a 'syntax error', which means you're having an error in the code itself, not the 'logic'.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  So this definitely has something to do with assigning the `$soapURL` right after it's been declared.  Perhaps I should assign it somewhere else?

Comment: You could override the constructor, setting the $soapUrl there. (And don't forget to call the parent constructor).