# Fatal error: Class 'sfConfig' not found while trying to include GMap class of sfEasyGMapPlugin in Symfony2

Tags: php, windows, symfony, netbeans, symfony1

Im trying to access the app.yml from a script outside Symfony and I'm getting an error 'Fatal error: Class 'sfConfig' not found' . For a similar issue in stack overflow it was mentioned  "you could either boot up Symfony or include the sfYaml parser and parse the app.yml yourself."

Can anyne explain this procedure. Im using Netbeans to create Symfony 2 project

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679974/access-sfconfig-class-in-apps-appname-lib)!'s the link to the answer I referred in stack overflow

I'm trying to setup the sfEasyGMapPlugin in my project.The class GMap.class is the one trying to access app.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't** add a symfony 1 plugin inside Symfony 2 !

You should give a try to these bundle instead:

- [egeloen/google-map-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/egeloen/google-map-bundle)

  > Provides a google map integration for your Symfony2 Project.
- [antimattr/google-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/antimattr/google-bundle)

  > The GoogleBundle adds the ability to add various google-related services to your application. These include Google Analytics, Adwords and Static Maps.